# Pure CSS Slider Scrolling Up on click of navigation

Tags: html, css

I am working on Mangoapps. I need to create a sliding banner. But I have to do it **using CSS and html only, there's no provision to write js for the banner (including reference to any js files)**.

I found these two types of pure CSS slider:

1. Using `<label>`tag for navigation e.g. http://codeconvey.com/Tutorials/cssSlider/. `<label>` isn't working properly with Mangoapps, asked for resolution to developer team already, though no answer yet.
2. Using `<nav>`/`<a>`. **The problem is whenever I click on next/prev it slides but scrolls up to the top.** I understand the cause, but I wanted to be fixed at it's position when clicked. Here is the jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/thisisdev4u/8s7u12jr/

Let me know, if this can be fixed or if there's any other way of making a pure CSS-based slider with navigation arrow/dots.

Comment: I think this [link](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_carousel.asp) can help you :)

Comment: @Batman - That's a bootstrap carousel. I have already mentioned that there's no provision for js.

Comment: I got some links which can help you to build your code without using js.
1) http://codepen.io/koheishingai/pen/uKvJF 
2) https://www.christianheilmann.com/2015/04/08/keeping-it-simple-coding-a-carousel/

Answer (score 0):

I made this pure-CSS carousel slider with 2 switch alternatives: **label arrows** and **radio buttons**.

I have no way to test it on ***mangoapps*** so if the `radio` buttons don't work there you can hide them with `display: none` and if the `labels` don't work there you can simply delete them.

[**Codepen 1**](http://codepen.io/freestock/pen/yOzbpq?editors=1100)

[**Codepen 2**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JXrpWV) - *alternative version with infinite animation rolling until any option be checked;*

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background: lavender;
}

#container {
  text-align: center;
}

#pic1, #pic2, #pic3, #pic4 {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 640px;
  height: 423px;
  margin: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s; /* Safari */
  transition: all 1s;
}

input[type=radio] {
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#sel1:checked ~ #canvas #pic1 {
margin-left: 0%;
}

#sel2:checked ~ #canvas #pic1 {
margin-left: -100%; 
}

#sel3:checked ~ #canvas #pic1 {
margin-left: -200%; 
}

#sel4:checked ~ #canvas #pic1 {
margin-left: -300%; 
}

.left {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40%;
  left: 5%;
  z-index: 200;
}

.right {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40%;
  right: 5%;
  z-index: 200;
}

#canvas {
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  width: 640px;
  height: 423px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  outline: 2px solid black;
}

.left, .right {
display: none;
}

#radio4_left, #radio2_right {
  display: inline-block; 
}

#sel2:checked ~ label#radio4_left,  #sel2:checked ~ label#radio2_right, #sel3:checked ~ label#radio4_left,  #sel3:checked ~ label#radio2_right, #sel4:checked ~ label#radio4_left,  #sel4:checked ~ label#radio2_right {
  display: none;
}

#sel1:checked ~ label#radio4_left, #sel1:checked ~ label#radio2_right {
display: inline-block;
}

#sel2:checked ~ label#radio1_left, #sel2:checked  ~ label#radio3_right {
display: inline-block;
}

#sel3:checked ~ label#radio2_left, #sel3:checked  ~ label#radio4_right {
display: inline-block;
}

#sel4:checked ~ label#radio3_left, #sel4:checked  ~ label#radio1_right {
display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id=container>

<input type=radio name=select id=sel1>  
<input type=radio name=select id=sel2>
<input type=radio name=select id=sel3>
<input type=radio name=select id=sel4>

<label class=left id=radio1_left for=sel1><img src="http://i.imgur.com/krGCplJ.png" alt=left></label>
<label class=right id=radio1_right for=sel1><img src="http://i.imgur.com/clLE3Db.png" alt=right></label>
<label class=left id=radio2_left for=sel2><img src="http://i.imgur.com/krGCplJ.png" alt=left></label>
<label class=right id=radio2_right for=sel2><img src="http://i.imgur.com/clLE3Db.png" alt=right></label>
<label class=left id=radio3_left for=sel3><img src="http://i.imgur.com/krGCplJ.png" alt=left></label>
<label class=right id=radio3_right for=sel3><img src="http://i.imgur.com/clLE3Db.png" alt=right></label>
<label class=left id=radio4_left for=sel4><img src="http://i.imgur.com/krGCplJ.png" alt=left></label>
<label class=right id=radio4_right for=sel4><img src="http://i.imgur.com/clLE3Db.png" alt=right></label>

<div id=canvas><img src="http://i.imgur.com/64v1WY4.jpg" alt=pic id=pic1><img src="http://i.imgur.com/jy9liDm.jpg" alt=pic id=pic2><img src="http://i.imgur.com/WdZd6J1.jpg" alt=pic id=pic3><img src="http://i.imgur.com/aLFYMgm.jpg" alt=pic id=pic4></div>
  
</div>
```